# Modify the SSH welcome message to include system IP address

Tags: ssh, login, customization, ip-address

I have had a couple of occasions where I was unable to remember the IP address for a given system but was, at the time, able to connect using the hostname.  As an example, just now I wanted to set up port forwarding on my router and couldn't remember the IP for the target system.

I am wondering if it is possible to add the system's IP address to the welcome message that gets displayed on an SSH connection.

The default welcome message that I am trying to modify, in case that term is ambiguous, is"

```
Linux [hostname] 2.6.35-32-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 3 00:47:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Ubuntu 10.10

Welcome to Ubuntu!
    * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
```

Somewhere in there I think I'd like to add the IP address of the system I just logged in to.  Any suggestions?  Other than trading in my brain for a newer model with more RAM?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The message you refer to is the "motd", or "Message of the Day". It's contained in `/etc/motd`.

This is generated by update-motd, documentation for which is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd#Design

See this related question: [How do I edit the ssh motd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23246/how-do-i-edit-the-ssh-motd)

To directly answer your question, you could add a file called `/etc/update-motd.d/50-ip-address` with this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig |grep "inet addr"
```

This will very simplistically add all the configured internet addresses on your system to the motd file.

The motd is updated "at each login" (as per `man update-motd`). You can play with the number as the first part of the script's name to decide the order in which the IP address will appear.

As the files in `/etc/update-motd.d` are simply shell scripts, you can write something as simple or as complicated as you want.

Comment: It won't let me vote you up yet, but your answer looks like it should do what I was hoping.  I'll try it out tomorrow.  Cheers!

Comment: Tested and confirmed.  Brilliant!   That gave far more info than I need but, as you said, it is a bash script so I'll have plenty to tinker with now to get it exactly where I want it.  That is, after all, half of the fun of running linux!

Comment: To test how it would look like without logging in again, run `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`. Although to see the changes in the next login, it has to be around 10 minutes or so after your last edit. Or try logging in a couple of times until you see it.

Comment: There's no such file in 18.04 bionic

Answer (score 21):

This may be more than you want/need, but the `landscape-common` package automatically adds system information, including IP addresses to the MOTD.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-28-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Jul 12 10:21:51 MDT 2016

  System load:  0.09                Users logged in:        1
  Usage of /:   12.3% of 225.17GB   IP address for enp7s0:  192.168.X.XXX
  Memory usage: 45%                 IP address for wlp9s1:  192.168.X.XXX
  Swap usage:   0%                  IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
  Processes:    397

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Jul 12 10:03:16 2016 from 192.168.X.XXX
```

Specifically, it adds a symlink to `/usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper` in the `/etc/update-motd.d/` directory.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I looking for this info for ages.

Comment: How can I disable `update-motd` completely?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna set a custom message, create a file in the `update-motd.d` folder & `chmod` it as shown below

```
sudo vi /etc/update-motd.d/01-custom
```

Add your custom message along with the ipconfig command to this

```
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig |grep "inet addr"
```

Or in modern Linux systems ipconfig is deprecated so use the below:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip a | grep "inet"
```

And then:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/update-motd.d/01-custom
```

Log out and log in to see your changed MOTD message.

Comment: apologies didnt finish completing the answer, posted by mistake