# Where does the System Information information come from on login by SSH?

Tags: ssh, login, system-info

When I connect to an Ubuntu 18.4 server with ssh I get the following information:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  
 * Management:     
 * Support:        

  System information as of Wed Apr  3 06:39:53 UTC 2019

  System load:  0.0               Processes:             151
  Usage of /:   9.5% of 48.96GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 11%               IP address for ens160: 192.168.xxx.xxx
  Swap usage:   0%

 * Ubuntu's Kubernetes 1.14 distributions can bypass Docker and use containerd
   directly, see xxxx  or try it now with

     snap install microk8s --classic

 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     ubuntu.com/livepatch

8 packages can be updated.
8 updates are security updates.


Last login: Wed Apr  3 06:27:23 2019 from 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

What is the command to get this information to print again?

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/update-motd.d/` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/100052/modify-the-ssh-welcome-message-to-include-system-ip-address).

Comment: You can run this with `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`.