# Network Interface on landscape-sysinfo (VPS)

Tags: networking, interface, landscape, vps

I have a VPS (Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS) with "landscape-sysinfo" *(from "landscape-common" package)*

When the info is shown it appears only 1 network interface (venet0 = 127.0.0.2) and not showing the second network interface venet0:0 (width the IPv4 External IP)

How can i enable to show the info of second network interface (venet0:0)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

landscape-sysinfo skips any network alias in the MOTD.

If you really want to have all alias listed, you could easily create your own MOTD script:

```
cat >/etc/update-motd.d/99-addr <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
ip -o addr show up scope global | awk '{print \$2"  "\$4}'
EOF
chmod +x /etc/update-motd.d/99-addr
```

[How do I edit the ssh motd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23246/how-do-i-edit-the-ssh-motd)